# How can I make the spinner width same as largest available item width

Tags: android

I realize even I use `wrap_content` for my spinner (I avoid using `match_parent` as I do not want the spinner overly long), and using `match_parent` for spinner's item view and drop down item view,

I still find the spinner's width is not same as largest item's width

[image]

As you can see, the `UnitedKingdom` is not fit.

So, if I select the `UnitedKingdom`, only the spinner's will resize

[image]

How can I make the spinner resize to the largest available item width, even without being explicitly selecting the largest item?

My spinner XML is

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

and my spinner's views XML are

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/text_view_0"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

---

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/checked_text_view_0"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp" />
```

Comment: Have you tried with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` ?

Comment: Which XMLs are you referring to?

Comment: Yes. I try. But that is not I want, as the spinner width will fill the entire dialog, which is overly long.

Comment: probably the best choice is to extends your textview and override onMesure

Comment: @Umair See my added so call - "Answer". Although I'm not 100% happy with the method, it works for me(TM).

Comment: I would go with custom spinners if none of these work.

Comment: Thanks @CheokYanCheng but my spinner data is dynamic. However, your answer can work in setting up initial UI :)

Comment: I've been battling with this issue for days. So far I only found a way to manually set the width of the dropdown, but not automatically match it to the content.

Comment: Setting up the `android:paddingEnd="0dp"` attribute on Spinner's xml tag solved my this issue.

Answer (score 19):

You should be able to get the effect you want by specifying the width of the dropdown as `WRAP_CONTENT`:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

This will measure up to 15 items in the spinner's adapter to determine the width it should use.

Comment: this does not work. i have hardly 5 items in the list and it still does not adjust the width according to the largest option.

Comment: @faizal - What version of Android are you running this on? It will only work when on a device or emulator running API level 16 or later.

Comment: i ran it on a Samsung Duos(GT-S5282) that has API 16(Android 4.1.2).

Comment: @faizal - Weird. Where are you using the spinner? If it's in the action bar, I seem to recall reading somewhere that it takes a little more work to get it to work right.

Comment: I used it inside a Linear layout, not in the action bar. I had to specify an explicit width of 120dp to make it work.

Comment: @faizal - You should post a separate question about this, including the layout and the code that uses the layout. The source code definitely shows the spinner measuring the first 15 items when it sets up the width of the drop-down. If there is a setup where this fails to work, it would help the community to know exactly what that is.

Answer (score 9):

I merely "solve" the problem by using

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

200dp is just try-n-error value, to ensure all items in the drop down list  are visible.

Comment: While this is the only method that actually works in terms of expanding the dropdown beyond the size of the original spinner, it doesn't really help in cases of dynamic values because you have to be able to predict the measured size of the row.

Comment: @EladAvron then we can reset the size dynamically again by finding the maximum value

Answer (score 3):

In such cases where you want to list all country or have big list
Try: `spinnerMode="dialog"` as shown below:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your TextView inside LineanLayout in Spinner Item XML,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/text_view_0"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And Pass your TextView's id to custom adapter constructor

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.spinner_item,R.id.text_view_0,arraylist);
```

**Constructor**

```
  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewId, ArrayList<String> resultList) {
                super(context, resource, textViewId, resultList);
        ...
        ...
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the `android:paddingEnd="0dp"` parameter on Spinner xml tag solved my issue.

Now the dropdown items list takes the width equal to the Spinner's whole width including it's dropdown arrow.

Answer (score -1):

Set your width to 0dp and a layout weight of 1. The following will resize it for you.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test label"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/test_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:prompt="@string/test_prompt"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try `spinnerMode="dialog"` but it is just a workaround, not the right answer. Because it will display a new window with a dialog.

So here is the way do to it. It will automatically fit the content.

It strongly depends how you set up your custom layout. May i suggest you to write your own xml file `myspinner_custom_dropdown.xml`. Recommanded way is now `ConstraintLayout` from androidX.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Important** : you have yo use your custom layout with your adapter

```
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.myspinner_custom_dropdown);
```

That's all, **you do not need some kinds of hardcored attributes in your spinner** declaration.

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

Answer (score -7):

Try this: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Comment: It's better to add detail about your code as well in the answer if needed.