# Spinner width android

Tags: android, width, android-spinner

How to fix the spinner dropdown list width equal to the spinner width?
Sorry this is repeated question but none of the given solutions has worked for me.

[How can I make the spinner width same as largest available item width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633705/how-can-i-make-the-spinner-width-same-as-largest-available-item-width)

Note: I don't want to set the width statically using setDropDownWidth(int dp);

Comment: have you tried with custom style??

Comment: Hii kishore jethava , as with custom style i can give the width as match_parent/wrap_content or some static width.. but in my case i am creating the spinner programmatically with layout_params, so i don't think it will help, If you know some way then please help me

Comment: @awadesh Then, if I didn't missunderstood you, do you want it programatically instead of in XML file?

Comment: @Error404 yes i want it programmatically , so that it is visible correctly in phone and tablet also. I am creating the layout for spinner using layout_weight

Comment: @awadesh I'm sorry I still didn't have confront with it. I just have it in an XML file and it's why I asked you :D